# Java Double brace initialization

Tags: java, eclipse, double-brace-initialize

I have refactored the following object initialization:

```java
Req r = new Req();
r.set_f1("A");
r.set_f2(123);
r.set_f3(123.456);
```

Into:

```java
Req r = new Req() {{
    set_f1("A");
    set_f2(123);
    set_f3(123.456)
}};
```

The second sample raises the following Eclipse warning:

> The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

I thought that these code samples should be equivalent - what's the difference?

Comment: These two are absolutely not equivalent, they're very different. SO is full of prior questions about double-brace initialization.

Comment: @duffymo You are absolutely wrong on this.

Comment: Why would you decide to "refactor" your original example in such a way?!  Double brace init isn't exactly a widely used practice!  How about making the constructor of Req accept that data:

Req req = new Req(x, y, z);

Comment: @skaffman Thanks. I was confused with this concept.

Comment: @Irly, yes I was absolutely wrong.  I'll rescind the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the base class implements `java.io.Serializable` then subclasses will should have a `serialVersionUID`. Inner classes should not be serialisable.

If you are planning objects created by this code to be exposed to other code that potentially might want to serialise the data, don't use the double brace idiom (I suppose you could use it with `writeReplace`, but that gets a bit ugly). If you are sure your code isn't going to come into contact with serilisation, stick `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` on the widest possible context.

Answer (score 6):

The second one creates an anonymous subclass and initializes it with an unnamed initializer. If the `Req` is serializable, any subclass of it is, and should hence define a `serialVersionUID`.